# Tips and tricks for activities in android

Tags: android, android-activity

Hi i'm developing an android app but i see my application isn't working the way its supposed to work for example my activity gets recreated when screen is rotated and gets destroyed when i go back to another activity and i'm using also sockets which make it even worse working in this condition. Anyone who knows some tips or tricks to avoid these problems for the application to be stable and work properly and don't lose any data when switching back and forth between activities. Any advice about activities is appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you need socket connections you should do this in a `Service`, not in activities. Services are independent of UI and have a much longer lifecycle. Network I/O needs to be done in background threads anyway (which are better managed in a `Service`).

Answer (score 0):

That is the way Activities work on Android.

When the configuration changes (for instance, the device is rotated, or the keyboard is displayed), the current Activity is killed and then restarted for the new configuration.

You normally have to handle this cases.

You can make the system handles some changes (like the device rotation) using `android:configChanges` in your manifest. Read this Google article about it:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html